# Horizontal RecyclerView of images

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, imageview, horizontal-scrolling

Which is the code to obtain a Horizontal RecyclerView of images? I already have the code for horizontal RecyclerView of Strings. I need to have the same but of Images. 
I have to create a RecyclerView of 10 horizontal scrollable imageView.
This is my actual code of 10 horizontal TextViews:

```
public class HorizontalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalAdapter.HorizontalViewHolder> {

private String[] items;

public HorizontalAdapter(String[] items) {

    this.items = items;

}

@Override
public HorizontalViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout_recycler_view_top_10, parent, false);
    return new HorizontalViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(HorizontalViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.text.setText(items[position]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.length;
}

public class HorizontalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView text;

    public HorizontalViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_top_10_ricette_titolo_ricetta);
   } }
}
```

and I manage it on a Fragment in this way:

```
        RecyclerView list = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_ricette_categorie_primi_top_10);
    list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
    list.setAdapter(new HorizontalAdapter(new String[]{"Android","Programming","Java","RecyclerView","Layout"}));
```

How I have to modify this?

Comment: Didn't understand. what exactly you want to ask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this make below changes in your **`HorizontalAdapter`**

```
public class HorizontalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalAdapter.HorizontalViewHolder> {

private int[] items;

public HorizontalAdapter(String[] int) {

    this.items = items;

}

@Override
public HorizontalViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout_recycler_view_top_10, parent, false);
    return new HorizontalViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(HorizontalViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.image.setImageResource(items[position]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.length;
}

public class HorizontalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView image;

    public HorizontalViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageviewid);
   } }
}
```

**code for RecyclerView**

```
RecyclerView list = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_ricette_categorie_primi_top_10);
    list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
    list.setAdapter(new HorizontalAdapter(new int[]{R.mipmap.ic_launcher,R.mipmap.ic_launcher,R.mipmap.ic_launcher,R.mipmap.ic_launcher,R.mipmap.ic_launcher}));
```

> **NOTE** : Your layout (`item_layout_recycler_view_top_10`) needs to contain a `ImageView` instead of a `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a recyclerView full of textViews (`R.layout.item_layout_recycler_view_top_10`) you want images?

Just create another layout which contains an `ImageView` instead of a `TextView` in it and use it accordingly to your current solution.

Answer (score 0):

String array change to image url array or drawable image array create and send to adapter and set into imageview.